# What is a good way to test a method that expects an HTML string?

Tags: ruby, rspec, expectations

```
foo.should_receive( :save ).with( html )
```

Where `html` is an HTML string, but I don't want to check against specific HTML because that would make the test brittle.

Is there a way to check the length of the param that foo should receive? Is it possible to use a matcher or something like `html.should include '<html'`?

Working in RSpec.

Comment: My question would be why does foo's save care if it's html?

Comment: Foo is a reporting model, and the test is to check the method that runs a report. I don't really care about the output of the report because there is no data in the test database. But it should save the report, and the report should be an HTML page.

Comment: If Save, converts it to HTML, it's doing to much. If it validates that it it's input is HTML, it's doing too much. If it doesn't then, it just saves whatever it gets passed, doesn't matter what it is, and a FileExists test, and maybe a read and compare to input with a small test file is all that is required.

Comment: You're right. The reporting model is doing two things: reporting and generating HTML. So we need a separate model for generating HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment above you can use a regex for the argument matcher.

```
foo.should_receive(:save).with(/<html/)
```

If you want to do more complicated assertions you can provide a block:

```
foo.should_receive(:save).with do |arg|
  arg.should include '<html'
end
```

Comment: Although technically a correct answer, the real answer is that we don't need to check the parameter. As Tony Hopkinson mentioned in the comments above, checking the parameter is a smell: The model is doing more than one thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why that would not work using the code you provided. Maybe use `include?` instead. You also could use a regex to determine if it was HTML. While for this specific example it might be a little much, you may be able to determine more specific things about the html then just if it has that tag.